# Arcpy Field Name Validate

Tags: arcpy, data-interoperability

I am using the arcpy.QuickImport_interop tool to convert AutoCAD files into feature classes based on the layer names as below:

```
arcpy.QuickImport_interop(os.path.join(subdir, file), temp_GDB + file + ".gdb")
```

Is there anyway I can call the arcpy.ValidateFieldName function within this to ensure that my generated tables have valid names and avoids crashing the script.

Comment: Do you get an error message? You should be able to use try-except to prevent crashes (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/executeerror.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BERA for the assistance. I have added a try-except statement to the query as below:

```
try:
      # Import the CAD files using the data interopability tools
      arcpy.QuickImport_interop(os.path.join(subdir, file), temp_GDB + file + ".gdb")

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
      print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

I will be adding a statement to log the errors to my log file so that drawings raising errors can be manually attended too.